# www I added to HTTP_HOST via htaccess file disappears when redirecting to second htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am struggling with an htaccess file. Actually, it is two files.
But first things first, so my questions are:

1) Why does my `.htaccess(1)` file add the www at the beginning of the HTTP_HOST and the slash at the end of folder REQUEST_URI ***IF AND ONLY IF*** the `.htaccess(2)` file is not there (deleted or renamed)?
2) What is wrong with the RewriteRule and conditions that I wrote in `.htaccess(2)` to redirect the `REQUEST_URI` to `/publicfolder/REQUEST_URI`? Conditions doesn't seem to work and when I surf to `domain.com/nonpublicfolder` it goes to `domain.com/domainfolder/publicfolder/nonpublicfolder`.

My website is structured as follows:

```
/
    .htaccess(1)
    domainfolder/
        .htaccess(2)
        publicfolder/
            genericfolder/
            index.extention
            file.extention
        nonpublicfolder/
```

So I have one htaccess file in the `root` folder ( `.htaccess(1)` ) where I:

- add 'www' at the beginning of the HTTP_HOST;
- add '/' at the end of REQUEST_URI if it does not end with a file extension;
- redirect `domain.com/anyfolder/anyfile.extention` to `domain.com/domainfolder/anyfolder/anyfile.extention`;

like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# System symbolic links are allowed.
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Runtime rewriting engine enabled.
RewriteEngine On

# HTTP_HOST starts with 'www'.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC]

# Folder requests end with '/'. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![^/]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,NC]

# Files and folders are in the 'domainfolder' folder.  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?domainfolder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /domainfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC]

</IfModule>
```

And then I have my `.htaccess(2)` file - in the `domainfolder` folder - where I redirect files and folders requests to the `publicfolder` folder ***IF AND ONLY IF*** they are not pointing to the `notpublicfolder` folder or to the Google Site Verification file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Runtime rewriting engine enabled.
RewriteEngine On

# Public files and folders are in the 'publicfolder' folder. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?domainfolder/publicfolder/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?domainfolder/nonpublicfolder/ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?domainfolder/googlexxx.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /publicfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Thank you very much for your time and patience.

Comment: This is a well framed Q.  However, my answer is slightly more general because it would simply take me too long to research a detailed answer.  However, I think that I've given you enough pointers now to crack it yourself.  Post back with specifics _after trying_ and we can discuss :-)

Answer (score 0):

(1) `mod_rewrite` does multiple passes and on each by default it will only open the first `.htaccess` file it finds walking up the folder hierarchy from the requested file. read my [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules) for more discussion of this.  Yes you can use a Options setting to change this behaviour but this has a performance hit and I would suggest that you avoid doing so.

(2) When using hierachical `.htaccess` files, mod_rewrite has to associate URI path to the current directory and can get this wrong. The `RewriteBase` directive tells mod_rewrite what the true association is, so use this.

Rule order is important.  If you don't have a local Apache instance where you have root privilege and can enable rewrite logging, you need to build up your access file(s) incrementally rule-by-rule, testing at each step because you only get a work/doesn't work return.  Again my tips explains how to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much @TerryE for your answer.  
I read your Tips thoroughly and I have to say I have considered all of them while building my`.htaccess` files. In fact, I worked on a single `.htaccess` file before I decided that splitting rules actually made more sense to me. And everything worked just fine. Now I lose rules effectiveness when redirecting to the second `.htaccess` file. How come? I don't get it.   The only thing I haven't tried yet is defining the RewriteBase. But this should only help me with the conditions I can't seem to get working, right?